# High-Charts selection event triggering wrong output on css transformed element

Tags: css, highcharts

I am using css transform to scale my highcharts container
when the element is scaled the returned output for selection event is not as expected i:e the selection event is not in sync with the mouse pointer what might be the issue on this???

I have attached the fiddle  [HIGHCHART](https://jsfiddle.net/gopalravi/vhewd4we/)`select the points in chart to see the issue`

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround here 
https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/1753

And I changed it to your needs. Please check if everything works.

```
(function (H) {
     H.wrap(H.Pointer.prototype, 'normalize', function (proceed, e) {
         var e = proceed.call(this, e),
             container = this.chart.container.parentNode,
             zoom;

         if($('#container').css('transform') != none){
            var zoom = parseFloat($('#container').css('transform').split(',')[3]);
            e.chartX /= zoom;
            e.chartY /= zoom;
          }

          return e;
      });    
}(Highcharts));
```

I built it in a new JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/k2bcszdx/. Let me know if there is something to change.

Comment: thanks for the answer..it works in fiddle but in my  project i have applied transform to the element which is the parent of the chart container i:e the overall wrapper that contains chart and other elements
will this make any difference?? because it doesn't work in my project

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle to explain the problem? Otherwise I have to guess the problem.